# Function to Burn a ERC721 token from a different contract

Tags: contract-development, erc-721, burn

I want to burn the token from a different contract, I know I would have to use an external burn function but can someone help me with some piece of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create an interface of the ERC-20 contract and create an instance of it with the address of the token contract. You can then call the burn function on it.

```js
interface IERC721{
    function burn(uint256);
}

contract BurnStuff {
    
    address _token;

    constructor(address token){
        _token = token;
    }
        
    function burnToken(uint256 _tokenId) public {
        IERC721(_token).burn(_tokenId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro I wanted to know about ERC721

Comment: Sorry, by bad. But if you had taken a look at ERC721 contract, you'll know what to do here. You just need to change `_amount` to `_tokenId`.